# CSS - center align divs even at runtime

Tags: html, css, alignment

Please refer - https://jsfiddle.net/L0hav8ma/2/

```
<div id="x">
<div id="x1"> div1 </div>
<div id="x2"> div2 </div>
<div id="x3"> div3 </div>
</div>
```

Requirement is to center align div1, div2 and div3 within the main div.

And also, at runtime using javascript i would have to remove div1 and div2. so even at that time, i want the div3 to be center aligned without any additional css changes.

Comment: what do you mean without any additional css changes?  how do you expect to do it then?

Comment: I meant, make single css changes. and when at runtime the 2 divs are removed, no extra css should be put and div3 should automatically center align. is this possible?

Comment: Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/L0hav8ma/3/

Comment: It was with your first fidlde, but not with your second - any reason you removed the `display:inline-block`?

Comment: All you need to do is add `display: inline-block;` to the children of `#x` and set `text-align: center;` on `#x`.

Comment: @pete - Yea, that is the present scenario! and div2 actually contains an image, and not just a text.

Comment: @gopalrao The content of the children does not matter, it will always align. The content is irrelevant. Also you should include all **relevant** code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#x {
  height: 70px;
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center; /* add this */
}
```